# SQL in query with elastic search sql

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-sql

I'm trying out elastic search sql. It works fine equal operator in where clause. But I couldn't use `in` operator in where clause. is there any equivalent command here. (like Terms filter)

```
POST _xpack/sql
{
  "query":"Select * from index_name where some_no in ( '12yrcs', 'ynelb') "
}
```

I get the following error.

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "sql_illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "Don't know how to translate In In[some_no{f}#3005,[12yrcs, ynelb]]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "sql_illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "Don't know how to translate In In[some_no{f}#3005,[12yrcs, ynelb]]"
  },
  "status": 500
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the time you tried ES-SQL the `IN` operator was not implemented yet probably: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/34622.
But now, this should be done and available.